# What does the CodeModel in Clang / LLVM refer to?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, code-generation

I have been looking through the Clang / LLVM source-code and I came across the `CodeModel` property of [`CodeGenOptions`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CodeGenOptions.html).

Based on [this method](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/CompilerInvocation_8cpp_source.html#l00320), the valid values appear to be: `"small"`, `"kernel"`, `"medium"` and `"large"`.

What do this property control?

How do I go about choosing the correct value for my application?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Code model is a term from AMD64 ABI (see 3.5.1 from https://www.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf for more information).

In short - the majority of the offsets inside x86-64 instructions are PC-relative, however the immediate field inside instructions is only 32-bit long. Therefore if the data is located "far" from the code (more than 32-bit apart), then one could not use immediate field inside the instructions to efficiently encode the offset and should calculate the address explicitly. The code model provides various restrictions on the relative location of code and data.

If you're compiling everything statically, then 'small' is safe (and default). If you're JIT'ing, then everything is possible especially if ASLR is enabled and you'd need to use medium / large code model.

Comment: FYI: `man clang | grep mcmodel` outputs nothing instead of description of `mcmodel`.