# What are code models and how do they affect code generation?

Tags: rust, llvm-codegen

In rustc, there are 4 code models. You can see the list by typing `rustc --print code-models`:

```
Available code models:
    small
    kernel
    medium
    large
```

What do they mean?

Comment: This looks very similar to [What does the CodeModel in Clang / LLVM refer to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40493448/what-does-the-codemodel-in-clang-llvm-refer-to) Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it answered my question, thanks for the grammar fix.